# NSUserDefaults doesn't save after app quits

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

When I quit the app, the values stored in NSUserDefaults isn't saved. I saved the values like this:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"enabled" forKey:@"notifications"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

How do I store something with NSUserDefaults even after the app quits?

This is how I retrieve the values:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"notifications"]
```

The first two lines do run, because I put them to run when a button is pressed. When I go to a different view and back to the one with the button, it returns the value that I set.

I see what was wrong. I has this code in the first view and assumed it was working properly:

```
NSUserDefaults *Def = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *Ver = [Def stringForKey:@"Version"];
NSString *CurVer = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary] objectForKey:(NSString*)kCFBundleVersionKey];
if(Ver == nil || [Ver compare:CurVer] != 0)
{
    if(Ver == nil)
    {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"disabled" forKey:@"notifications"];
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your value which you put in setValue? Right now, you set it as a string "enabled". And how do you refer to it?

Comment: When does the app quit, and how, in relation to that code running (are you sure it did run)?

Comment: What is the printout of the "notifications" key of nsuserdefaults?

Comment: use this:NSLog("%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"notifications"]);
can you tell me what it print?

Comment: That log prints "enabled"

Comment: I believe I can just use `setValue` to save a string?

Comment: Saying "because I put them to run when a button is pressed" is not proof they ran, there may be a problem with the button. You have to prove the save code ran, one way is to put a `NSLog()` right after them. Then immediately retrieve and `NSLog()` the result. How do you quite the app?

Comment: There is a log after it, and it says the value i set it to. I quit the app by either double pressing home button and sliding it up or pressing stop button in xcode.

Comment: Add a retrieval and NSLog in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` `applicationWillTerminate` and `applicationDidEnterBackground` and `applicationWillEnterForeground` to determine if is valid prior to termination and immediately after becoming active.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the wrong methods.

`valueForKey` and `setValue:forKey:` are methods pertaining to [Key Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html), and aren't related to setting your persistent data in `NSUserDefaults`.

You need to be reading your values with

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"notifications"];
```

and writing with

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"enabled" forKey:@"notifications"];
```

Comment: That doesn't save it after the app quits still.

Comment: @somepers I didn't include this in my answer, but you'll still need the synchronize call if you kill the app immediately after setting the new object (i.e. before the defaults have the opportunity to be automatically synchronized).

Comment: If you're testing this in the simulator, I've noticed that NSUserDefaults doesn't save if you stop debugging or quit the simulator. Instead, you have to return the simulator springboard with Cmd+Shift+H first, and then stop debugging.